# Swift - Using UISearchBar to filter key value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Getting some practice in building a simple app. Here I am trying to search through a table view. This has me stumped. I just can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I already tried error handling which got it up and running but no matter what I type it just returned nil. Any help will be much appreciated.

Library sample code:

```
import Foundation

struct BenchmarkWODs {

static let library = [
    [
        "name": "Angie",
        "exercises": "100 Pull-ups/n100 Push-ups/n100 Sit-ups/n100 Squats",
        "description": "For Time Complete all reps of each exercise before moving to the next."
    ],
    [
        "name": "Barbara",
        "exercises": "20 Pull-ups\n30 Push-ups\n40 Sit-ups50 Squats\n\nRest precisely three minutes between each round.",
        "description": "5 rounds, time each round"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Chelsea",
        "exercises": "5 Pull-ups\n10 Push-ups\n15 Squats",
        "description": "Each min on the min for 30 min"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Cindy",
        "exercises": "5 Pull-ups\n10 Push-ups\n15 Squats",
        "description": "As many rounds as possible in 20 min"
    ],
```

Detail file code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct WOD {

var name: String?
var exercise: String?
var description: String?

init(dictionary: [String: String]) {

    name = dictionary["name"]
    exercise = dictionary["exercises"]
    description = dictionary["description"]



}

}
```

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class BenchmarkWODViewController: UITableViewController,     UISearchResultsUpdating {

var wodList = [WOD]()
var searchController : UISearchController?
var resultsController = UITableViewController()
var filteredWODS = [String]()

var results = WOD(dictionary:["": ""])






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for wodData in BenchmarkWODs.library {
        let wod = WOD(dictionary: wodData)
        wodList.append(wod)
    }

// Search Bar
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController?.searchBar
    self.searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self



}

// Search Bar Function
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:   UISearchController) {

    let result = results.name
    filteredWODS.append(result!)
    filteredWODS = self.filteredWODS.filter { (result:String) -> Bool in
        return true

    }

    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()






}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wodList.count
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BenchmarkCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let wod = wodList[indexPath.row]

        if let wodName = wod.name {
            cell.textLabel?.text = wodName
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code over github or something similar so that I can have a look into it.

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: https://github.com/Brandon-316/WOD-Guide